# Will to show the div on same line any class is there?

Tags: html, css

I want to show the three div on same line using style display-inline block and width other than this style any css3 class is available.

**Code:**

```
<div id="1" style="display:inline-block;width:10%"> </div>
<div id="2" style="display:inline-block;width:10%"> </div>
<div id="3" style="display:inline-block;width:10%"> </div>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say

Comment: Me neither. Please take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you maybe want to have three divs next to each other? If so, please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804273/how-to-align-3-divs-next-to-each-other

Comment: I need any inbuilt classes like col are there in css

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are asking, but if you want to use classes instead of inline styles and having the divs aligned, you can do it using this css:

**HTML**

```
<div id="1" class="inlineDivs"> </div>
<div id="2" class="inlineDivs"> </div>
<div id="3" class="inlineDivs"> </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.inlineDivs{
  display:inline-block;
  width:33%;
  float:left;
  background:deepskyblue;
  min-height:200px;
  border-right:1px solid black;
}
```

Usually, after some floating divs I also use a clearfix div.

check how it looks here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVvVER